# Azure Arm templates dynamic array variable

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

We have Arm template to create multiple VMs for that we are looping using copy, now we need to have dynamic availability set for each VM. User either selects availability set or selects none. How to handle resource availability set in both scenarios for multiple vms.

For single VM I am creating two variables one with a option either none or select, other variable with condition

```
Parameters:
"Availabilitysetstatus": {"type":"string", "allowed aliens":  
["member","none"]}
"Availabilitysetname": {"type":"string", "defaultvalue":""}

Variables:
"Availabilitysetconfig":{
"Member":{"id":"concat("....", parameters 
('availabilitysetname'))},
"None":{}
}
```

While creating resources I am using below in property for availabilityset

```
"Availabilityset": "[variables ('Availabilitysetconfig') 
[parameters ('Availabilitysetstatus')]]"
```

This is working fine but my resources are creating multiple VMS using loop copy, 
so my availabilityset should be array i.e
 Availabilitysetstatus, Availabilitysetname are array then how can we create array for Availabilitysetconfig to use in loop with copyindex

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure I completely follow your scenario, but in general, if you have variable/conditional resources, there are template functions that can help with this - see: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/create-flexible-arm-templates-using-conditions-and-logical-functions/

That help?